# Hide Admob Ads programmatically with Swift

Tags: ios, swift

My admob ads is loaded from `viewDidLoad`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
            let bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait)
            bannerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0,
                                      y: UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.size.height,
                                      width: bannerView.frame.width,
                                      height: bannerView.frame.height)
            bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-myID"
            bannerView.rootViewController = self
            bannerView.loadRequest(GADRequest())
            view.addSubview(bannerView)
    }
```

I am trying to do a function to hide the ads using:

```
func removeAds () {
        let bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait)
        bannerView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
```

However, this is not working. What's wrong did I made?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating entirely new instance of AdView here

```
func removeAds () {
        let bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait)
        bannerView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
```

You need to define you instance of AdView Globally for the Current Class above view did load

You can achive this with code below

```
var bannerView : GADBannerView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
           bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait)
            bannerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0,
                                      y: UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.size.height,
                                      width: bannerView.frame.width,
                                      height: bannerView.frame.height)
            bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-myID"
            bannerView.rootViewController = self
            bannerView.loadRequest(GADRequest())
            view.addSubview(bannerView)
    }
```

and you can remove that addView with

```
func removeAds () {
        bannerView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I got the error "expected member name or constructor call after type name" for the line `var bannerView = GADBannerView!`

Comment: Replace the `=` with a `:` @user2872856

Comment: did it helped ? @user2872856

Comment: Got the error "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". Actually I am calling this function from another class. I have a class which handle in-app purchase remove ads. After successful purchase, the ads in another class should be hidden.

Comment: You can not remove Adview from another view. Instead after succsfull purchase you can maintain flag either to show ad or not. You can check for appropriate in viewWillAppear.

Comment: My Answer will help if you are on current view. Where ad is.